# magmi configurable product multiple prices for same option

Tags: magento, magmi

I am trying to import configurable products into magento using magmi.

Consider simple products for configurable :

```
Product,   Color, Quantity, Price
Product 1, Blue,  100,      10    
Product 2, Blue,  50,        5
Product 3, Red,   50,        6
```

Problem that I am facing is that product might have different quantities which will have different prices.

So configurable options would look like this:

`Quantity::50:5;50:6`

Is there any solutions to disambiguate which price is for which option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming this is what you're wanting as your question lacks detail.

1. Customer views configurable product with drop-down (configurable) options
2. Customer selects drop-down attribute values and hits add to cart.
3. The simple product (that matches the selected attributes) is added to the cart including the price for that simple product.

Magento does not do this out of the box.  If you want the actual simple products to be added to the cart along with their prices, you'll need to modify Magento with an extension that does this.

Personally I use [Simple Configurable Products](https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple) which does exactly what I've described above.

Then in Magmi, you simply upload the simple products, and also one configurable product that has those simple products associated to it.  You can use the [simple_skus column](http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Configurable_Item_processor) in the CSV for the configurable product to define which simple products are assigned to the configurable product.

Just make sure your simple products are imported before you import the configurable products.  You can simply make sure the configurable product is BELOW all the simple products in the CSV datasource file you import.